# In VB.NET/C#, how do I copy a SQL table schema from on DB to another?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I want to move a table schema from one database to another using vb.net or c#. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26459/Copy-Database-Schema-and-Data-Using-SQL-Server-Man) show how to use SQL Server Management Objects (SMO), C# to Script, Copy Database Schema with or without data.

```
public class DBHelper
{
    #region Private Variables
    private static string sourceSQLServer;
    private static string destinationSQLServer;
    private static string sourceDatabase;
    private static string destinationDatabase;
    #endregion 

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// SourceSQLServer Holds Instance Name of Source SQL Server Database Name
    /// </summary>
    public static string SourceSQLServer
    {
        get { return DBHelper.sourceSQLServer; }
        set { DBHelper.sourceSQLServer = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DestinationSQLServer Holds Instance Name of Destination SQL Server Database Name
    /// </summary>
    public static string DestinationSQLServer
    {
        get { return DBHelper.destinationSQLServer; }
        set { DBHelper.destinationSQLServer = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SourceDatabase Holds Source Database 
    /// </summary>
    public static string SourceDatabase
    {
        get { return DBHelper.sourceDatabase; }
        set { DBHelper.sourceDatabase = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DestinationDatabase Holds Destination Database Name
    /// </summary>
    public static string DestinationDatabase
    {
        get { return DBHelper.destinationDatabase; }
        set { DBHelper.destinationDatabase = value; }
    }
    #endregion 

    #region Static Methods
    /// <summary>
    ///  CopyDatabase Copies Database 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="CopyData">True if Want to Copy Data otherwise False</param>
    public static void CopyDatabase(bool bCopyData)
    {
        //Set Source SQL Server Instance Information
        Server server = new Server(DBHelper.SourceSQLServer); 

        //Set Source Database Name [Database to Copy]
        Database database = server.Databases[DBHelper.SourceDatabase];            

        //Set Transfer Class Source Database
        Transfer transfer = new Transfer(database);

        //Yes I want to Copy All the Database Objects
        transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;

        //In case if the Destination Database / Objects Exists Drop them First
        transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;

        //Copy Database Schema
        transfer.CopySchema = true;

        //Copy Database Data Get Value from bCopyData Parameter
        transfer.CopyData = bCopyData;

        //Set Destination SQL Server Instance Name
        transfer.DestinationServer = DBHelper.DestinationSQLServer;

        //Create The Database in Destination Server
        transfer.CreateTargetDatabase = true;      

        //Set Destination Database Name
        Database ddatabase = new Database(server, DBHelper.DestinationDatabase);

        //Create Empty Database at Destination
        ddatabase.Create();

        //Set Destination Database Name
        transfer.DestinationDatabase = DBHelper.DestinationDatabase;

        //Include If Not Exists Clause in the Script
        transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true; 

        //Start Transfer
        transfer.TransferData();

        //Release Server variable
        server = null;
    }
    #endregion 
}
```