# Copy Access table structure and constraints using C# or SQL

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, schema

Can someone tell me how to copy an MS Access table's table structure and all its constraints, keys, and etc. using .NET or SQL? I have searched and found a number of ways of copying the columns and types, but I need to bring across the constraints as well such as primary keys.

I have a database with a bunch of tables which I need to create copies of (structure only) with new names. This needs to be executed from within a C# application, but I do not care if it is done using ADO or SQL, just as long as I can find a way. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a table schema and constraints to a table of different database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600172/how-to-copy-a-table-schema-and-constraints-to-a-table-of-different-database)

Comment: Copying an access table to another access table?  Or to another database system?

Comment: Keith: Database is a Microsoft Access 2007. Also, the link you provided addresses the same issue for SQL Server, but it does not work for MS Access as there is no way to generate scrips for a table within Access (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Phoog: I want to create a copy of an existing table within the same database. If the copy to be created already exists, I will delete it first, then generate a fresh copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "export" to the same database, which will create a copy with all indexes etc, but not relationships.

```
        // Start a new instance of Access for Automation
        oAccess = new Access.Application();

        // Open a database
        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"z:\docs\test.accdb");
        oAccess.DoCmd.TransferDatabase(
            Access.AcDataTransferType.acExport,
            "Microsoft Access",
            @"z:\docs\test.accdb",
            Access.AcObjectType.acTable, 
            "table1",
            "newtable",true,false);
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks a ton. For full disclosure, I had to add a .Net reference to my project for "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access", version 12 as I'm using Office 2007.

Comment: I need to do a little more testing tomorrow to make sure it takes care of everything and then I'll mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the upsize wizard with MS Access

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237980

Comment: Micah: thanks for the link, but it details how to convert an older (97 & 2000) access database to SQL Server using external tools. The issue I am having is how to create a structural copy a table within a MS Access 2007 db from a C# application.

Comment: ah take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905090/in-vb-net-c-how-do-i-copy-a-sql-table-schema-from-on-db-to-another

Comment: does this work with MS Access? I'm doing a little digging and trying now but if you know already...